# Виртуализация или как сделать, чтоб listbox с большим количеством данных не глючил?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть listbox и в него надо загрузить, скажем, 1000 значений. Если загружаю в DataGrid или DataView, то всё загружается моментально и не "лагает". А когда загружаю из базы в ListBox, имею в лучшем случае секундную задержку, пока он выгрузит всё в память. Насколько я понял, в листбоксе он всё сразу выгружает в память [хотя с нынешними процессорами это не проблема, короче, делает что-то ещё, что грузит программу], а в гриде, только видимый участок плюс ещё немного.

В книге Мэтью Макдоналда по WPF 4.0 пишется про виртуализацию и после этого листбокс нормально работает. Вообщем я так сделал, но по прежнему у меня такая же проблема.
Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: Вообщем я взял компонент Teletik-а и там лист бокс нормальный....не парю голову, почему же там не работало....

Answer (score 3):

Если есть что-то типа `BeginUpdate, EndUpdate` (могут называться иначе), попробуйте вызвать первое перед началом изменения и второе после всех изменений.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте.

Считаю себя профи в узких местах кода, касающихся интерфейса. Сталкивался с такой проблемой. Все дело скорее всего в том, что используется неправильный xaml в исходных файлах разметки. Наши "профи" плохо проверяют скорость работы, только чтобы было красиво.

Решается все просто, надо откорректировать стиль Template. В месте, где есть такое (в частности в ListBox):

```
<StackPanel IsItemsHost="true"  ...    />
```

Надо сделать правильно:

```
<ItemsPresenter ... выравнивание и т.п. ... />
```

Кстати, оно не только ускоряет работу, но и позволяет правильно отображать собственные стили ListBoxItem. 
P.S. Сам я тестировал, так что даже ума не приложу, зачем они используют вместо нормального ItemPresenter свойство панели IsItemsHost